# How could I access a private object from another class?

Tags: java, field

Is there some direct or indirect way to access a private object from another class?

Comment: Reflection is the only way.

Comment: If you're trying to access a private object from another class you're doing it wrong...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Actually, you can do it with native methods as well.

Comment: @HotLicks Are native methods not restricted by access modifiers? (I've never developed native methods.)

Comment: but Im sure using reflection may be faster than using a native method? Unless of course there is some native method that is faster than reflection, _Please tell me!_

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I don't recall the details, but there definitely are access restrictions on using native methods (just as there are on using reflections).  Link - A native method would almost certainly be faster than using reflection, if the native code were written to access a specific field in a specific object type.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H41x56RG is my latest revision for the class I am trying to use this in. This class is *supposed* to break OOP because well, its like a mini JVM so to speak. Please don't ask me why I would be doing this; it's part of a game library I just started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, reflection is really your only hope on this one.  It'd be the only way you could inspect an object's fields without caring much for its visibility modifiers.

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
for(Field f : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    try {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(f.get(entity));
    } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But, I do want to ***strongly*** caveat you on resetting the accessibility of the field.

If you're running in a highly concurrent environment, and you disable the accessibility immediately after you're done, you will run into a case in which the accessibility is removed in one thread, as you're about to read it in another, which will lead to a giant, confusing mess.

At that point, the fact that you *have* visibility modifiers becomes moot, and you would want to just use a part-and-parcel getter instead (or have the field be `public`, which makes many feel weird about).

Comment: that is exactly, more or less what I do if you look at Initializer.java line 100 - 103. But can I *set* the value as well?

Comment: Yes, there is a `get()` method attached to the `Field` class.  Further, you **really** shouldn't be casting those `Field`s to `Object`, as that means you have to do unnecessary casts to get them back.

Comment: Each thread is going to have its own method-local Field instances, so there's no concurrency issues here (unless of course you use the Field to change the entity's state).

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to create getter/setter methods for your private variables.

E.g.

```
private String myData;

public String getMyData () {
   return myData;
}

public void setMyData (String myData) {
    this.myData = myData;
}
```

If you do not want to do this then you can use reflection to access the private variables.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: Perhaps I should have highlighted *FULLY AUTOMATIC* before finishing; I explicitly do state *The object's class should have no relation to this class except to make a new object of it and is only used by the main class of the program really.* Thank you for the tutorial though on reflection :)

Comment: What the heck does FULLY AUTOMATIC mean?  I have not come across that programming term before.

Comment: Well you can infer and be correct about that since the object should have no relation to this class except to make a new object, then why would you make a getter and setter since it changes them for you and they may be private objects not meant to be changed by anything but what initializes it as well as the class it was declared in.

Comment: As you could consider using aspectJ

Answer (score -1):

You can't access private object/variable from another class. A way to do that is to used getter and setter:

public class Sample{
    private String name;

```
//setter
public void setName(String yourname){
    this.name = yourname;
}

//getter
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

}

class AccessPrivateVariable{
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
    Sample sample = new Sample();

    /*call the setter from Sample class and pass value
    to its parameter*/
    sample.setName("Andrew");

    /*
    access the name "Andrew" by calling getter
    */
    System.out.println("Welcome " + sample.getName());
}
```

}

Comment: Nope. people, reflection can access private methods, but I DONT KNOW HOW! That is what would be useful. everyone saying it isn't possible, well by all means I would not do so ordinarily unless oh say the purpose was to debug a class and *Initialize any null object!?* yeah... that is the reason...

Comment: LinkTheProgrammer I gave a you a link to a tutorial and @Makoto sensei gave you some sample code.